# dynamic row to column update

Tags: oracle

I have a table A (column_name,value) which stores the metadata information. 
 I have another table B which has columns as rows of A with some additional system columns. 
For example if table A has two rows `(empID,1)` and `(salary,200)` then table B will look like `B(empid,salary,system_id,create_date,update_date)`. 

I need pl/sql procedure which will update B and set empid as 1 and set salary as 200. The rows in A and columns in B can change dynamically.

Comment: Can you provide the _actual_ table structures as this sounds like you're making it more complicated than it should be. Dynamically updating things is normally an indication of a bad design than anything else as it shouldn't be necessary. Databases are, by design, fairly static.

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of columns and values from table A, build a statement and execute immediate:

```
declare
 cols varchar2(2000);
begin
 for a in (select * from a) loop
   cols := ','||a.column_name||'='||a.value||cols;
 end loop;
 cols:=substr(cols,2);
 execute immediate 'update b set '||cols;
end;
/
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6976/8 for an example.

But I wonder how you are going to build the where - clause with your current DB structure. Currently you have no way to relate rows in table A to build where clause for table B.